# AJAX call to differrent page in same domain works, but does not load everything

Tags: javascript, ajax

So, a little context: I'm trying to do an ajax call to a webpage in the same domain to get a telephone number to show up as soon as I specify the client on the first page. I do get the data but it seems like not the whole page is loaded in.

I need this:

```
<div id="1">
    <div id="2">
        <a id="ineedthis"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

but instead it's giving me this:

```
<div id="1">
</div>
```

This is a website that I'm writing a script for, since I can't edit the source code. This is managed from our ERP program and is pretty limited in customizability.

My best guess is that the target webpage is also still loading in the information from the database, but my ajax call returns the webpage before that happens.

Here is my js code:

```
function updateClasses(){

  var link = $('a[href^="/organisatie-beknopt-prs?BcId="]');

  var href = "https://52134.afasinsite.nl" + link.attr("href");

  console.log(href);

  if(href !== "https://52134.afasinsite.nlundefined"){
               $.ajax({
               url:href,
               type:'GET',
               success: function(data){

               var tel = $(data).find("#P_C_W_Title_Content");

               console.log(tel);
               }                  
            });
       }
}

    setInterval(updateClasses, 1000);
```

I'm running this once per second to check for a change in the input field on the first page, I don't know if there is a better way for this?

Comment: console.log(href); which show in console?

Comment: This outputs the correct url, being https://52134.afasinsite.nl/organisatie-beknopt-prs?BcId=851, basically just adding the id at the end

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you could try running the script/function once a change has been detected.

Something along the lines of :

```
$('input[name="{inputFieldName}"]').on('change',function(){
    updateClasses();
});
//You can also use "keyup" instead of "change", depending on the type of action that you are looking for.
```

For the Ajax, you could try using Promises. Basically, set up the ajax call and then set a ".done" case for the ajax call has been completed and received some result. A ".fail" can also be used to catch non-code related issues.

```
function updateClasses(){

   var link = $('a[href^="/organisatie-beknopt-prs?BcId="]');

   var href = "https://52134.afasinsite.nl" + link.attr("href");
   var getPhonePromise = $.ajax({
         url: href
   });

    getPhonePromise.done(function(data) {
        var tel = $(data).find("#P_C_W_Title_Content");
        console.log(tel);
    });
    getPhonePromise.fail(function(errRes) { console.log(errRes);});
}
```

Comment: The on change function doesn't work, I tried deviations of that function and couldn't get any of them to work, no idea why.
For the ajax part, I implemented your method of promises (didn't know about this, thanks), but it is returning the exact same data as my previous ajax call

Comment: Can you post the related html/javascript codes for the input? Also, what kind of response are you expecting from the ajax?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by codes for the input? I'm expecting the full html contents of the page. It's like the page loads in html first and then updates the page content after it's loaded, but ajax just returns the first state of the webpage (like it doesn't wait for the contents to get filled in). I need the contents of <div id="1">, but it's showing up as empty, when I would need this:

<div id="2">
        <a id="ineedthis"></a>
 </div>